# SQL Server insert: using a static value to determine date value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am inserting production orders into a SQL Server database with a stored procedure called via Microsoft PowerApps. Currently, the build date column is just using today's date as the build date. Attached below is a sample of records:

[image]

As you can see, all 10 of these orders have today's date as the set build date. However, I'd like to dynamically set this build date based upon the necessary output for the day. This will most likely be passed a variable to the stored procedure. For example - if the build output was 5 per day, rows 1-5 would have a build date of '02/17/2020' while the next 5 would have have a build date of '02/18/2020'.

This is simple enough since the number of orders is divisible by the build output. However, let's say the build output is 3 instead of 5. The first three orders would be '02/17/2020', the next three would be '02/18/2020', and the next three would be '02/19/2020'. This would leave one order to be set to '02/20/2020'. Then if I added more orders, it would stack upon each date filling each up to 3. Is there a way to do this via a stored procedure?

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to do some adjustments but based on my understanding, this will do the trick ([Date] is the date column in your sample table above):

```
CREATE PROC yourProcName @pNUM AS INT = 1 --PARAMETER
AS
(
    DECLARE @pDate DATE;
    SET @pDate = COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(DATE, MAX([Date])), GETDATE()) FROM yourDestTable); --SETTING THE DATE AS MAX DATE ALREADY EXISTS IN THE TABLE. IF NOTHING IS THERE, WE'LL USE TODAY
    DECLARE @pLead INT = COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM yourDestTable WHERE [Date] = @pDate), 0);--SEE HOW MANY RECORDS IN THE DATABASE EXIST WITH THE DATE WE DEFINED
    WITH cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT *,
        FLOOR((
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @pDate) -
                0.001)/@pNUM) AS RN -- SEPARATING RECORDS USING ROW_NUMBER DIVIDED BY DEFINED NUMBER OF PRODS PER DAY. USING FLOOR AND MINUS A SMALL AMOUNT TO ROUND IT RIGHT
        FROM yourSourceTable
    )
    INSERT INTO yourDestTable
    SELECT
        C.*,
        DATEADD(DAY, LEAD(C.RN, @pLead), @pDate) AS [Date] --PUSHING THE NUMBER BASED ON ROWS ALREADY EXISTED WITH THE MAX_DATE
    INTO yourDestTable
    FROM cte AS C
)
```

You might want to use MOD in CTE based on your usecase. But the idea should work. Then call it like this `EXEC yourProcName <number of transactionsday>`

Comment: Thank you for the code.. would you mind explaining your answer a bit?

Comment: Happy to help. Would appreciate it if you mark it as an answer.
I'll comment the code